# PostgreSQL - treat array values as records in a query

Tags: postgresql

I want to treat an array of timestamps as a set of records that could be related with other tables.

For example:

```
SELECT array[0], COUNT(b.id) FROM array, B WHERE B.date > array[0]
```

What's the best way for achieving something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [the `unnest` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

```
regress=> SELECT arraycol 
          FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]) arraycontent(arraycol);
 arraycol 
--------
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
(5 rows)
```

You can join on the array's contents; `unnest`, being a set-returning function, can be used like any other `FROM` term.

If your PostgreSQL is too old to have `unnest` then it's too old to run, too. Start planning an upgrade.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the arraycontent function, I can't use the column as a normal column which I can use in WHERE clause.

Comment: @william `arraycontent` isn't a function, it's a table-alias. "label the results of the unnest function 'arraycontent' with single column 'arraycol' for reference elsewhere"